# How to set all buttons in a controlgroup to the same height when some have two-row labels?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, button, label

I want to create a row of multiple buttons to form a coherent block in jQuery Mobile. For this, I placed them in a horizontal controlgroup. This approach works well for simple labels, but now I want to have one or more buttons with two rows of text on them. For example:

```
<form>
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">  
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="left">Left</a>
  <a href="#" data-role="button">Middle item<br/><sub>Second row</sub></a>
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="right"></a>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

[Example on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mwil/4qKkf/)

My problem is that the multi-row labels appear fine, but the other buttons on the row still have a width appropriate for a single-row label (or no label). The result looks like this:

[image: controlgroup with three buttons and messy labels]

How can I ...

- make all the buttons have the same height?
- center the one-row button labels vertically to the new height?
- center the icons vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try this:

- First Step : assign an id for your `<fieldset>`

  ```
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="t">
  ```
- Second Step : changes in your css for the `a` tag

  ```
   #t a {
    float:none;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
   }
  ```

View the Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/4qKkf/12/**

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the [`display: table-cell;`](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) trick which allows you to give the links a uniform height and allows vertical centering by use of `vertical-align`

CSS:

```
a[data-role] {
    display: table-cell; 
    float: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4qKkf/14/

Comment: It's better if you don't use `!important`

Comment: I've also included the jQuery Mobile selectors if he wants to override  them.